# WPForms textarea doesn't display when published on a page in WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form, siteorigin

I'm using Be Theme in WordPress, and I'm using WPForms to create a contact form.

The form was set up correctly in the WPForms Builder (as far as I am aware), and I'm using the following shortcode in the SiteOrigin Editor (with paragraph turned off): [wpforms id="397" title="false" description="false"]

And this is the result:

[Contact form with no textareas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIucd.png)

I was thinking maybe there was a conflict between the SiteOrigin / WPForms / Be Theme, but I'm not sure. I also did some searching on Google, but I couldn't seem to find anything that addressed this exact situation that I'm dealing with.

Thank you to anyone who decides to help!

Comment: I also tried using Contact Form 7, but the same thing happened. No input fields.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

I was using some CSS (to get rid of this ugly line that went through the page), and I guess it also disabled the input fields.

It's fixed now!